# How to end program after right answer?

Tags: javascript

I've made a game with JavaScript where a player can only guess a random number from 1 to 10 three times, each time the program reads a wrong answer it displays what should've been the right answer, and tells the player to try again, if the player gets the right answer the game displays a message saying **You got it right**. I've managed to make the program work, and apparently, everything seems to be fine, except for one thing, the program won't stop even after the player gets the right answer, it reads through all the statements until it reaches the end. **How can I make it stop after the right answer?**

```js
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 3 chances.");
if (answer == random) {
  alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
} else {
  alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random);
  window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 2 chances left.");
}

if (answer == random1) {
  alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
} else {
  alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random1);
  window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 1 chance left.");
}

if (answer == random2) {
  alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
} else {
  alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random2);
  alert("You've lost");
}
```

Comment: Please use triple equals in Javascript. You can convert this in a method and add a return statement to stop the rest of the method from executing if they get the correct answer.

Comment: Return statment --> `return;`

Comment: You could use `return` or set and read some state, depending on context. Also, you may wish to use some form of iteration, which could make that simpler and also reduce duplicated code.

Comment: Do you logic in a loop with return statement.

Answer (score 3):

### First and forement, the bug

You have a bug in your code. If you win on the first round, it will detect this successfully. On the second and third round, any victory will be purely coincidence.

The reason is because you do not assign the return value from `window.prompt` to `answer` every time you call it. So the value of `answer` never changes from one round to the next.

To fix this, you should replace

```
window.prompt(...)
```

with:

```
answer = window.prompt(...)
```

### The "bad" fix:

Let's start with a very simple (but very ***bad***) solution, and use it as a springboard to teaching better architecture design.

Your current code roughly looks like this:

```
if (win) {
   // say you won
} else {
   // say you lost
}



if (win) {
   // say you won
} else {
   // say you lost
}



if (win) {
   // say you won
} else {
   // say you lost
}
```

With all of the extra stuff cleaned up you can clearly see why it's going through all three iterations: the three if/else blocks are entirely unrelated and know nothing about one another. It runs one if/else block, then another, then another -- in order, every time.

The easiest fix is to make sure the later blocks **only run if you lose**. This is pretty easy to do, because we already know if you lost -- it happens when you didn't win!

```
if (win) {
   // say you won
} else {
   // say you lost
   if (win) {
      // say you won
   } else {
      // say you lost
      if (win) {
         // say you won
      } else {
         // say you lost
      }
   }
}
```

Or, using your `random`, `random1`, and `random2` variables:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 3 chances."); 
if (answer == random) {
    alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!"); 
}
else {
    alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random);
    answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 2 chances left.");
    if (answer == random1) {
        alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!"); 
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random1);
        answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 1 chance left.");
        if (answer == random2) {
            alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!"); 
        }
        else {
            alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random2);
            alert("You've lost");
        }
    }
}
```

This is ugly, but will work.

### Springboarding into better design

As you might imagine, adding 4 or 5 or 6 rounds to this game would get REALLY tedious. You'd have to type out **even more** if/else blocks, create **even more** random variables, and type out **even more** alert statements. To make it more annoying, all of these alert statements contain the same text!

There's a concept in software design called [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself). This means that if you have two identical lines of code, you can probably rewrite it to eliminate the duplication.

In your case, we can do this using a `while` loop to check if we've won the game or not:

```
var youHaveWon = false;

while( ! youHaveWon ) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10");
    if (answer == random) {
        alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!"); 
        youHaveWon = true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to keep making guesses until you get it right, and doesn't repeat any code. Although this **doesn't** limit you to only 3 guesses. To do that, we should introduce one more variable:

```
var youHaveWon = false;
var guessesRemaining = 3;

while( ! youHaveWon && guessesRemaining > 0 ) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10... you have " + guessesRemaining + " more guesses");
    if (answer == random) {
        alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!"); 
        youHaveWon = true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random);
    }
    guessesRemaining = guessesRemaining - 1;
}

if ( ! youHaveWon ) {
    alert("You lost");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this to a function and return it on right value. Upon return, JS will stop execution and control will move forward

Try below

```js
function findNumber() {

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

  var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 3 chances.");
  if (answer === random) {
    alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random);
    window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 2 chances left.");
  }

  if (answer == random1) {
    alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random1);
    window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have 1 chance left.");
  }

  if (answer == random2) {
    alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + random2);
    alert("You've lost");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're having three different if-blocks which all will be executed even though the user might have guessed the correct number yet.
I'd recommend setting up a single random number and a global counter which keeps track of the remaining chances.

```js
function validate() {
  if (answer == random) {
    alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
  } else {
    if (chances - 1 > 0) {
      chances--;
      answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have " + chances + " chances.");
      validate();
    }
  }
}

var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var chances = 3;
var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have " + chances + " chances.");
validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomNumbers = [];
var numberOfTries = 3;

for(var i=0; i<numberOfTries ; i++){
   randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));  
}

for(var i=numberOfTries-1; i > -1 ; i--){
   var answer = window.prompt("Make a guess from 1 to 10, you have "+ parseInt(i + 1) +" chances left.");
   if(answer === randomNumbers[i]) {
      alert("HORAAYYYY YOU GOT IT RIGHT!!!");
      return; 
   }
   else {
      alert("Sorry, the correct answer was " + randomNumbers[i]);
   }  
}
```